# Handshake Parity

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, arithmetic

Every person on earth has already shook hands with a certain number of people. Show that the number of people who shook other people's hands an odd number of times is even.

What I thought:

Denote people with vertices. Connect a pair of vertices (if they shook hand with each other) with an edge. Sum the number of edges each vertex is connected to (it's degree). This must be even as each edge is counted twice. It follows that there are even no of people with odd handshakes

Comment: Please consider giving your question a more informative title.

Comment: Also, while the question is implicit by the [tag:proof-verification] tag, it would be better to make it explicit, ask whether your argument is correct in the question. Not everybody reads all the tags on a question (I usually don't).

Comment: Can I imagine the simplest graph? 2 vertices and one edge, both vertices have odd degree

Comment: Of course you can imagine the simplest graph. But what would be the point of doing so? You need all loopless finite graphs, not just one. It is not necessary to explicitly use graphs to prove this. Just count handshake-sides. Whenever two people shake hands, each's count of handshake-sides increases by 1 and the total number of handshake-sides increases by 2, So the total number of handshake-sides is always even, and is the sum of the the handshake counts of all the people. Removing the sum of all people with even counts leaves the sum of odd counts and an even total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply checking if your answer is totally correct? It is!

The argument you give for the sum of degrees is important in graph theory and you may have seen it expressed as

$$2E=\sum_1^V \rho_i$$

for a graph with $E$ edges and $V$ vertices.